Why select html element look so much different in Safari with a plan select in Safary?
I do turn off all the css attributes for a select item in Safari, but it will still not look at a plain select in in Safari, why?


I would have the first, I did try those, but not brings closer to the upper one:
style={{
    padding: '10px',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    fontSize: '15px',
    display: 'inline-block',
    appearance: 'auto',
}}


Does this answer your question? CSS reset that sets everything to default values

I suggest you should create a custom dropdown to handle such request.
/* Hide the default select element */
select {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* Create a custom element to mimic the select */
.custom-select {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer; /* Indicate clickable behavior */

    /* Add custom styles here (e.g., background color, border) */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* Style the dropdown options (requires additional HTML and JavaScript) */
.custom-select-options {
    /* Styles for the dropdown list */
    display: none; /* Initially hidden */
    position: absolute; /* Positioned relative to the custom select */
    /* ... other styles for dropdown list */
}

This approach completely hides the default select element and creates a custom element (e.g., a <div>) with your desired styles. You'll need additional HTML and JavaScript to manage the functionality of the dropdown list (opening, closing, selecting options).

I will provide you with two approaches
1. If you do not care about the drop down menu styling
You can use appearance: none and set your styling that will work the same on all browsers
like this


.container {
  position: relative;
}

.arrow {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 99px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.sort_bar {
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  /* border-radius: 8px; */
  background-color: #F0F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
  color: #0F1111;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  /*for caret*/
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(15, 17, 17, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(15, 17, 17, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(15, 17, 17, .15);
}
<span class="container">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <select class="sort_bar">
            <option>Sort by: Featured</option>
        </select>
    </span>



2. If you do care about the drop down menu styling
you will need to create a drop down menu to hold your list, that can be toggled with javascript on click


const select = document.querySelector(".sort_bar");
select.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hide");
})

const listItems = document.querySelector("ul");
listItems.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("ul").classList.toggle("hide");
})
.arrow {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 99px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.isMenu {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #F0F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
  color: #0F1111;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(15, 17, 17, .15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(15, 17, 17, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(15, 17, 17, .15);
}

.sort_bar {
  position: relative;
  /*for caret*/
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.allContainer {
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #F0F2F2;
  border: 1px solid #D5D9D9;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
}

li {
  padding: 0.2rem 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:not(.first) {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
<span class="allContainer">
        <span class="container">
            <div class="sort_bar isMenu">
            Select
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </span>

<ul class="isMenu hide">
  <li class="first">Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
</span>



you can in both approaches insert a caret-icon to replace the dot of course. and toggle on it a class that will rotate it 180 degrees or something.
